# Expand Registry Environment Variable Strings on Remote Machine

Tags: c++, winapi, registry

After calling `RegConnectRegistry(...)` to open the registry on a remote machine, is it not possible to expand environment variables? I have looked at `ExpandEnvironmentStrings` and `ExpandEnvironmentStringsForUser`, but that only appears to be useful on the local machine. I think it must be possible considering that `RegistryKey.GetValue()` in .NET does expand the variables after calling `RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey()`, but I need to do this outside of .NET.

Any ideas?

Comment: The documentation for RegistryKey.GetValue() (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fdf576x1.aspx) indicates it expands environment strings using data from the *local* environment.

Comment: Yeah, I know that .Net method expands, like I said above. There is a new method that also expands, but it is only for Vista and above - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724868(v=VS.85).aspx.

Comment: I should of read Luke's comment closer and read the msdn documentation closer to see that does expand based on the local environment.

Answer (score 2):

Given that the environment variables running in a given process is based on the currently logged on user, how would you determine the set of environment variables that would be active on the remote machine?

Even if you could read that information (it's in the registry after all), what would you do about processes that change their environment?

Comment: I need to expand registry key values under local machine under EventLog to get message resource dll path(s).

Comment: Given that the .Net function that does what you want expands environment strings using the current environment variables, couldn't you just call ExpandEnvironmentStrings on the string?

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Seeing now that the .Net function only expands based on the current environment that would be the way to go.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up using this query: select windowsdirectory from Win32_OperatingSystem. I only needed to expand %SystemRoot%.